# Client.php file terminal is showing error of undefined variable version but I think that variable is defined

Tags: php, laravel

```
public static function cleanup_php_version($extra = PHP_EXTRA_VERSION)
{
    $version = PHP_MAJOR_VERSION . '.' . PHP_MINOR_VERSION . '.' . PHP_RELEASE_VERSION;

    if (!empty($extra) && preg_match('{^-(?<extra>(beta|rc)-?([0-9]+)?(-dev)?)}i', $extra, $matches) === 1) {
        $version .= '-' . $matches['extra'];
    }

    return $version;
}
```

In the laravel project I had install a vender package using composer install command when I again run the project It is showing

> Undefined variable version

but I check the code and It looks that it is already defined.

Comment: Can you indicate which line the error is being reported on.

Comment: yes error is indicated on the ( return $version ; ) line

Comment: In Clinet.php file the line no is 1551

Comment: I also check my php version it is 7.4 which is sufficient for all versions of laravel